# Выделенная область на JS

Tags: javascript

Смотрите, когда мы хотим получить выделенный текст на странице (наплюем на IE), то мы пишем вот так (ну и хотим получить из него Range-объект):

```
var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

Но я хочу не во всем объекте **window** искать, а только в каком-то своем узле:

```
var node = document.getElementById('id');
```

Но просто подставить **node** вместо **window** не получается. Что же делать?

Comment: В JavaScript есть методы call и apply позволяющие вызывать методы объектов в контексте нужного объекта. Попробуйте так:

    var myGetSelection = window.__proto__.getSelection;
    myGetSelection.call(node).getRangeAt(0);

Comment: а это тут при чём?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно обратиться к элементам, задействованным в выделении, то можно использовать

```
selection.anchorNode //здесь началось выделение
selection.focusNode //здесь закончилось выделение
```

а так getSelection - метод window (что логично, т.к. одновременно в окне сделать два выделения нельзя)